# javascript not working in MVC webgrid after sorting or paging

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am newbie in MVC and trying to polish concepts on `webgrid`. I have the following code in `view`

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCMovies.Models.Movie>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";      

 }
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('tbody tr').on('hover', (function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
    }));
    $('tbody tr').on('click', (function () {
        alert('rajeev');
    }));
});
</script>
 <style type="text/css">
   .table {
   margin: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
}

.head {
    background-color: #11E8CD;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #CC6699;       
}

.webGrid th, .webGrid td {
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    padding: 5px;
    color:white;
}

.altRow {
    background-color: #E4E9F5;
    color: #000;
}

.gridHead a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.description {
    width: auto;
}

.selectRow {
    background-color: #0B7BEB;
}
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ffff99;
}
</style>
<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div>
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div style="float:left">Title : @Html.TextBox("SearchString")<br />         </div>
        <div style="float:left; padding-left:5px">
        <input type="button" value="Filter" class="btn" />
    </div>
    }
 </div>
  <div id="grid">
     @{
     var gd = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 2, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
        @gd.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table");
   }

 </div>


     @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Now i have jquery written code for click on row functinon but it is stops working after i sort or do paging in webgrid

Comment: what error comes when run the code?

Comment: No error but javascript code stops working.. I.e no alert msg after sorting on row click

Comment: Are you dynamically updating the table rows? - if so, use event delegation - `$(document).on('click', 'tr', (function () { ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On sorting the table content get refresh. try this

```
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('click', 'tbody tr', (function () {
            alert('rajeev');
        }));
        $(document).on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
            }
        }, 'tbody tr');
    });
```

Comment: correct! on sorting table's tr gets generated every time, so events has to be delegated as you are doing.

Comment: Its working for `click` only. `hover` part still not working even on first time load

Comment: you can do using mouseenter and mouseleave. Check now

Answer (score 6):

The ajaxUpdateCallback is the name of the javascript function that will get called after the server call is complete. This would allow you to call your jQuery function after paging or sorting.

```
 @ { var grid = new WebGrid(data, ajaxUpdateContainerId : "grid", 
            ajaxUpdateCallback: "callBack");
   }
```

Comment: This is the best procedure to handle and bind the events.
nice effort and answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegates:

```
$(function() {
    $('tbody').on('hover', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
    });
    $('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
       alert('rajeev');
   });
});
```

Your initial code binds the event handler directly to the `tr` elements. On sorting and paging, the row a re-rendered and so the handlers are lost.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        $('tbody tr').live('hover', (function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
        }));
        $('tbody tr').live('click', (function () {
            alert('rajeev');
        }));
    });
  </script>
```