# How to bind javascript function or call during webgrid binding?

Tags: javascript, webgrid

I have a web grid which looks like following with more than 1000 records.

```
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: @Model.PageSize, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "suppListGrid");
grid.Bind(@Model.SearchResultSupplierViewModels, rowCount: @Model.TotalPageRows, autoSortAndPage: false);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
footerStyle:"pp-pagenumber",
            htmlAttributes: new {id="suppListGrid"},
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(format: (item) => @Html.Raw("<div class='row panelLawfirmresultbox'><span class='blue'>Panel Partnership Rating ("+item.PanelRating+"): </span><span class='panelStars'>"+"2.5"+"</span></div>"))
     )) 
}
```

And my above webgrid have a rating span which used to show the panel rating in the form of stars. In order to display panel rating stars i have used the following way.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('span.panelStars').panelStars();
    });
$.fn.panelStars = function () {
    return $(this).each(function () {
        $(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
    });
}
</script>
```

At present during the first page load everything works fine, showing the correct starring for my first 10 records. But when i click on next page, starring function not functioning.

When i checked [javascript not working in MVC webgrid after sorting or paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386735/javascript-not-working-in-mvc-webgrid-after-sorting-or-paging) link, the author mentioned that On sorting the table content get refresh, so events has to be delegated.

So in my document ready i added the following script like

```
$(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $('span.panelStars').panelStars();
            $('span.clientStars').clientStars();

            $.fn.panelStars = function () {
                return $(this).each(function () {
                    $(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
               });
            }
}, '#suppListGrid tr');
```

Now the starring came back but with full starring, but it will only come while mouse comes over tr tag.

But what i need is to happen the same on my page click. How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ho i resolved my problem by adding a small line of code with my webgrid control.

I added the following line of code in webgrid control

```
ajaxUpdateCallback: "getStars"
```

and created getStars() function i declared like this

```
function getStars()
{
    $('span.panelStars').panelStars();
    $('span.clientStars').clientStars();

            $.fn.panelStars = function () {
                return $(this).each(function () {
                    $(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
                });
            }

            $.fn.clientStars = function () {
                return $(this).each(function () {
                    $(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
                });
            }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. this helped me in a slightly different case. Just as a reminder, the ajaxUpdateCallback is specified as a parameter when constructing (new) the webgrid.

Comment: Happy to hear that mickeymicks